# json array value from volley into hashmap string, string

Tags: java, android, json, string, android-volley

i have a request to build slider image from `jsonArray` using volley, i don't know how to put value of `jsonArray` to `hashmap<string, string>` .. it keep saying null object

error message

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object
java.util.HashMap.put(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

JSON array value

```
[
     {"cPID":"62001002280293829",
      "image":"http:\/\/ibigcreative.com\/dev\/assets\/images\/slider\/rsch.jpg"},
     {"cPID":"62001002020254584",
      "image":"http:\/\/ibigcreative.com\/dev\/assets\/images\/slider\/penang.jpg"},
     {"cPID":"62001002050264258",
      "image":"http:\/\/ibigcreative.com\/dev\/assets\/images\/slider\/guardian.jpg"}
]
```

and then i wanna put that value like this into `hashmap<string, string>` inside `onCreate()`

```
HashMap<String,String> url_maps = new HashMap<>();
        url_maps.put("Hannibal", "http://static2.hypable.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/hannibal-season-2-release-date.jpg");
        url_maps.put("Big Bang Theory", "http://tvfiles.alphacoders.com/100/hdclearart-10.png");
        url_maps.put("House of Cards", "http://cdn3.nflximg.net/images/3093/2043093.jpg");
        url_maps.put("Game of Thrones", "http://images.boomsbeat.com/data/images/full/19640/game-of-thrones-season-4-jpg.jpg");
```

it gonna use for adding picture to my slider(slideshow) inside `onCreate()`

```
for(String name : url_maps.keySet()){
            DefaultSliderView DefaultSliderView = new DefaultSliderView(getContext());
            // initialize a SliderLayout
            DefaultSliderView
                    .image(url_maps.get(name))
                    .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit)
                    .setOnSliderClickListener(this);

            //add your extra information
            DefaultSliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
            DefaultSliderView.getBundle()
                    .putString("extra",name);

            mDemoSlider.addSlider(DefaultSliderView);
        }
```

and i don't know how to put values from `volley` `JsonArray`, and this is my request but error saying null.

```
private void getSlider(){

        String tag_string_req = "sliderList";
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request

        JsonArrayRequest mostReq = new JsonArrayRequest(AppConfig.URL_Slider, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                try  {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                        JSONObject jObj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        url_maps.put(jObj.getString("cPID"), jObj.getString("image"));
                    }
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + "Error Data Occured!!" + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();

            }
        }) ;
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(mostReq, tag_string_req);
    }
```

the values request was accepted on volley, it show on `Logcat` .. but null on `hashmap` .. tell me if i got mistake in my code, sorry just newbie and still study

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating thru just the keys... You need to iterate through the keys and values...

```
for (url_maps.Entry<String, String> url_map : url_maps.entrySet()) {
    String key = url_map.getKey();
    String value = url_map.getValue();
    // ...
}
```

ANOTHER WAY TO ATTEMPT THIS IS...

to deserialize your Json into a java object...

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

string StringJson = "[
     {"cPID":"62001002280293829",
      "image":"http:\/\/ibigcreative.com\/dev\/assets\/images\/slider\/rsch.jpg"},
     {"cPID":"62001002020254584",
      "image":"http:\/\/ibigcreative.com\/dev\/assets\/images\/slider\/penang.jpg"},
     {"cPID":"62001002050264258",
      "image":"http:\/\/ibigcreative.com\/dev\/assets\/images\/slider\/guardian.jpg"}
]";

// For the following line to work you will need to make a URLMaps Class to hold the objects

URLMaps urlMaps = mapper.readValue(StringJson , URLMaps.class);
```

The URLMaps Class might look like this.

```
public class URLMaps{
    public string name = "";
    public string image = "";

    //constructor
    public URLMaps(string a, string b) {
        name = a;
        image = b;
    }

    public string getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public string getImage() {
        return image;
    }
}
```

Then to utilize the class you can go with:

```
urlMaps.getName(), or urlMaps.getValue() in your DefaultSliderView.image()
```

Also to note, since this is a class you can store an array of them or a list of them, so you can re-purpose your for loop...

`For (URLMap urlmap : UrlMaps[])` // where URLMaps is your object that holds multiple instances of URLMaps.

Lastly, it has been a long time since I have coded in Java, so this code is untested, but should help you come to a solution.

Comment: keep error .. i think my mistake on mapper .. would you let me know, what to do in `volleyRequest` value ..

Comment: I see your problem... Check the top of my solution. I think you are only iterating thru keys, and you need to also iterate thru the values, to get the data.